# How can i reset all commits in repository without losing local changes

Tags: git, github

**Problem**

I clone my old resportory where I keep config but whene I clone it new resposytory inherited somehow old reposytory commits :P . I want to delete this commits to start with a clean slate.

Comment: 1) delete the `.git` folder then 2) `init` a new git repository 3) push the files to a *new* git repository (i.e., if you want a github repo or some such remote repository).

Comment: @topsail I do what u said but those commits are still there

Comment: You mean.... they are still _in the remote_, right? They can't be in the local repo after having deleted `.git`  and run `git init`.

Comment: Ok i move files to new folder and it worked new thanks for help